# Commutative diagram with upward arrows outside

Tags: tikz-pgf, commutative-diagrams

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amstext,  amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, euscript}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
  TM \ar[r, "{\rm d}f"] \ar[d, "\pi"] & TN \ar[d, "\pi"] \\ M \ar[ur, shift right = .25ex, "{\rm d}f \circ X"]  \ar[ur, shift left = .25ex, "Y \circ f"]  \ar[r, "f"]  \ar[u, bend left = 50, "X"]  & N \ar[u, bend right = 50, "Y"]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

I know very little of `tikz-cd` and I can do only simple triangle and square diagrams. I'd like to have:

- a bigger diagram, with everything more spaced, a bit longer arrows, etc;
- the two diagonal arrows labeled, being df o X the upper one and Y o f the lower one;
- the label Y in the rightmost arrow be on the right, and not on the left of it.

I browsed the site a bit looking for a similar diagram but I couldn't find anything. I could only get what's in the image and I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the `column sep` and `row sep`; label positions can be swapped from the default placement on the left of the arrow.

You don't need to load `amstext` (`amsmath` does it) and `amsfonts` (`amssymb` does it).

Also, the `{\rm d}` syntax has been deprecated for more than twenty years. Using `\diff` as defined also puts a thin space where appropriate.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, euscript}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4em,row sep=4em]
  TM \ar[r, "\diff f"] \ar[d, swap, "\pi"] & TN \ar[d, "\pi"] \\
  M
  \ar[ur, shift right = .75ex, swap, "\diff f \circ X"]
  \ar[ur, shift left = .75ex,  "Y \circ f"]  \ar[r, "f"]
  \ar[u, bend left = 50, "X"] &
  N \ar[u, bend right = 50, swap, "Y"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot, and for the extra tips too! Just for curiosity, what does that "swap" do?

Comment: @IvoTerek With `swap` you declare that the following label is placed on the right of the arrow (determined like you do with rivers). You can even place two labels, with `\arrow[r,"a",swap,"b"]`.